# best chemical to kill off grass but leave the trees alive

Tags: herbicide, chemicals

I have a patch of my garden with some rain trees interspersed with grass (I think its st Augustine)
[image]

my question is: which chemical can I use to kill off the grass but leave the trees intact?

location is Orlando, Florida

Comment: Not St. Augustine, it grows with runners/rhizomes.

Comment: @blacksmith37, could be. how do I get rid of them? I usually cut them with a bread knife, careful not to hit the trees. but that is very labor intensive

Comment: You should pull them to get the roots . Cutting will have little affect .

Comment: @blacksmith37 that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. this is a small patch of the garden and pulling them all out is a lot of work